# Film about the USA being run by fake videos of the president after his kidnapping

Tags: story-identification, movie

I am looking for a film from the 70's or 80's where the president of the United States of America is kidnapped (possibly kept underground) by a group who then produce fake videos (using some type of photo-realistic CGI) of him to run the country.

Comment: Was this a sci-fi or fantasy film?

Comment: It is a political science fiction.

Comment: What **specifically** makes it science fiction?

Comment: Realistic fake videos of people generated by computers in the 70's which are now possible using modern technology.

Comment: photo-realistic CGI in the 1970s is definitely Scifi

Comment: @Valorum why? It's a proven fact they could do it in 1969 ;) ;) ;)

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica - I remain resolutely convinced that they faked the moon landings ... using a studio set on Mars

Comment: Not the correct answer, but I'm reminded of the film "Dave" in which the president's body double is coerced into standing in for the president permanently, after the president suffers a heart attack.

Comment: @Valorum Stanley Kubrick was such a stickler for accuracy that he faked the Moon landings on location.

Answer (score 19):

You may be thinking of the 1973 Woody Allen film [*Sleeper*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sleeper_(1973_film)) ([IMDB](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0070707/)). Woody Allen plays Miles Monroe, who was cryogenically frozen in 1973 and revived 200 years later. America is run by an authoritarian government, lead by a dictator called "the leader", and Miles falls in with some rebels trying to take down the government.

We never see the leader speak or make any public appearances. He is seen a few times in photographs and generic footage with a narrator. I understood the depiction of the "generic footage" to be in-universe stock footage of the leader, rather than CGI.

During the final part of the film,

> we learn that the leader was killed almost a year previously by a rebel bomb. Scientists managed to save the leader's nose, and plans to clone a new leader from the nose. Monroe manages to steal the nose out of the operating room, is chased by the authorities, and finally assassinates the leader by throwing the nose under a futuristic-looking [road roller](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Road_roller).

Comment: Thank you for your recommendation but this does not seem to be the film I am looking for.